# AlpineJS not initializing in dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, django, alpine.js

I am creating a custom searchable select widget in my django application.

When returning the template normally all is well, however Alpine is not initializing when I render this field dynamically inside a modal. I use HTMX to make the ajax request; Django responds with a template and the template gets inserted into the DOM/modal.

#### Things I've tried

1. Adding my `Alpine.data`'s data directly into the x-data. This works but there is quite a lot a would like to avoid it if possible
2. Hacky ways to try initialize Alpine but does not work (maybe I've missed something)
3. Hooking into HTMX beforeSwap event to try load the JS before the template (no dice)

If anyone knows how to remedy this it would be greatly appreciated

#### Template

```
<div x-data="autocomplete" x-init="init('{{ widget.value }}')" class="relative">
# template stuff...
</div>
```

#### Script

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('autocomplete', () => ({
    open: false,
    selectedValue: '',

    init(value) {
      if (!['None'].includes(value)) {
        this.selectedValue = value;
      }
    },

    # functions used inside the template...

  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should explain better with examples the context and what have you tried, the request is unclear

What I can see that is wrong is that you are initializing thethe *selectedValue* property using the *x-init* directive which calls the *init()* method: with AlpineJs 3 the *init()* method is automatically called as soon as the object is created, so the result is that it runs twice, once by itself and once with your x-init.

You can make sure of this by simply adding a console.log() in *init()*:

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

    Alpine.data('autocomplete', () => ({

        open: false,
        selectedValue: '',

        init(value) {

            console.log ('Tadah!', Date.now());

            if (!['None'].includes (value)) {
                this.selectedValue = value;
            }
        }

    }));
});
```

The correct way is to pass the initial parameter using the *x-data* as explained [here](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#initial-parameters):

```html
<div x-data="autocomplete('{{ widget.value }}')" class="relative">
   .....
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

        Alpine.data('autocomplete', (value) => ({

            open: false,
            selectedValue: '',

            init() {

                if (!['None'].includes (value)) {
                    this.selectedValue = value;
                }
            }
        }));
    });
</script>
```

However, you could rename the *init()* method for example to *myInit()* and call it with *x-init* directive, but it seems a little verbose to me